# What does APC do with static content

Tags: php, apc

Let's say that I force mod_php to take in `.html` files.  Let's say that there's 0 PHP code in one of these files.

If I browse to that file with APC enabled, what happens?  Does it get cached or does it still have to be read from the disk?

The other scenario, I have a `.php` file.  What happens to the content outside PHP tags?  Does it get stored in memory?  Or does it have to be read from the disk every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I browse to that file with APC enabled, what happens? Does it get cached or does it still have to be read from the disk?

If you have `.html` files set to be parsed as PHP, then yes -- it will be cached. Sort of.

Specifically, PHP will generate an optree for the document, which ends up being a very short and boring program with a single very large string constant in it. This will end up getting stored in memory. HOWEVER, if that's all you're after, you'd be much better off using something like [`mod_mem_cache`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mem_cache.html) (unrelated to memcached!) instead, as it's actually designed to cache static content.

> The other scenario, I have a .php file. What happens to the content outside PHP tags? Does it get stored in memory? Or does it have to be read from the disk every time?

As I alluded to earlier, content outside PHP tags is still treated as part of the PHP "program" -- although it's treated a little differently internally, a chunk of static text surrounded by `?> ... <?php` (or at the beginning or end of a file) is effectively treated as if it were in an `echo "..."`. (Except without all the gotchas involving escaping within that string.) For instance, the following two code blocks are functionally more or less identical, other than some differences in whitespace:

```
<?php
  if ($condition) {
      echo "Hello";
  }
?>
```

vs.

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
    Hello
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't want to implement this.  Was just curious.

Comment: Does the same sort of thing then happen for php files with html outside of the php tags?

Comment: Edited to cover that! Short version: Yes.

Comment: Incidentally, this is a good reason to not parse static files (like HTML) as PHP unless you absolutely need to -- running them through the PHP parser slows things down, and will end up blowing more useful opcodes out of your APC cache.